# Area of triangle using float typcasting cpp

Tags: c++, integer, return, std, void

**my solution to find area of a triangle when base and height is given(the question specifically asked to also use float typcasting):**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int area() 
{
    int b=7,h=5;
    float area;
    area=(float)b*h/2;
    return area;//Write a expression to find Area as float using typecasting
}
```

**correct solution:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void area() 
{
    int b=7,h=5;
    float area;
    area=(float)b*h/2;
    cout<<area;
}
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `int area()` Don't you think you should return a `float`?

Answer (score 0):

By itself I would say nothing much.

- When you want to calculate a floating point number, makes sure ALL you values are floating point. Eg. not 2 but 2.0f
- Casting in C++ is usually done with static_cast (or one of the other cast functions). The notation you use is more "C" style type casting
- I am not a big fan of using, "using namespace" specially in larger projects. In source it can be ok, NEVER do this in header files though.

I would code it like this:

```
float calculate_triangle_area(const int b, const int h) noexcept
{
   float area = static_cast<float>(b) * static_cast<float>(h) / 2.0f;
   return area;
}

std::cout << calculate_triangle_area(5,7);
```

Some more notes:

- I always make things functions as soon as I can give it a name. This has the added benefit of making your code more "self explaining".
- The "const int" this mean you promise you won't change the values of b and h in your calculations.
- The noexcept is another promise, but that's a whole topic on its own ;)